# Trying to understanding startup procedure of monit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monit

I am just starting to learn monit. On its man page I found this:

> The behavior of Monit is controlled by command-line options and a run
>   control file, ~/.monitrc, the syntax of which we describe in a later
>   section. Command-line options override .monitrc declarations.

And when I created my .monitrc file with the following content and test it, it showed errors and I changed it and it is fine now:

```
➜  brt_client git:(master) ✗ monit -t                    
/home/jgu/.monitrc:2: Warning: Program does not exist: 'echo'
➜  brt_client git:(master) ✗ vim ~/.monitrc              
➜  brt_client git:(master) ✗ vim ~/.monitrc
➜  brt_client git:(master) ✗ monit -t      
➜  brt_client git:(master) ✗
```

but when I do `service monit restart`, I got this:

```
➜  brt_client git:(master) ✗ service monit restart
 * Stopping daemon monitor monit                                                                                                                                                                      [ OK ] 
 * Starting daemon monitor monit                                                                                                                                                                             empty config, please edit /etc/monit/monitrc.
```

So I checked the code in /etc/init.d/monit and found this:

```
CONFIG="/etc/monit/monitrc"
monit_check_config () {
  # Check for emtpy config.
  if [ "`grep -s -v \"^#\" $CONFIG`" = "" ]
  then
    echo "empty config, please edit $CONFIG."
    exit 0
  fi
}
```

So if I am not wrong, this program does not take -c or other flags. And I checked the log in `/var/log/monit.log`, it did not show that I restarted it. Of course, according to the script, it just exited with 0(why it is exiting with 0?).

So I checked the file, turns out I do not have the access to read `/etc/monit/monitrc`. So get sudo privilege for moinit and tried again. It is fine.

So now comes the actual question:

I did not find anything related to "~/.monitrc" in /etc/monit/monitrc, like "include ~/.monitrc", only include the directory in conf.d, how does monit know to load .monitrc in home directory? (By magic?)

And let's say I logged out and my college login to my computer with his account, does that mean my configuration will not work for him at all?

But that `monit reload` should have happened right? (if it does not get reloaded, then my ~/.monitrc should still be functioning)

Answer (score 1):

The `.*rc` files in user home directory are usually meant for providing some user-specific defaults while system-level defaults are usually given in a `*rc` file under `/etc` for the same application.

`man monit` ought to tell you this:

> `~/.monitrc` Default run control file
>
> `/etc/monitrc` If the control file is not found in the default location
>   and `/etc` contains a `monitrc` file, this file will be used instead.
>
> `./monitrc` If the control file is not found in either of the previous
>   two locations, and the current working directory contains a monitrc
>   file, this file is used instead.

However, since you are telling that in your case the default run control file is `/etc/monit/monitrc` instead of `/etc/monitrc` there might also be other deviations from what the developers have written in the man page (or it might be that the man page is out-of-date, or your question has incorrect path for that file).

In the context of running `monit` as a service the above would mean that it is defaulting to `.monitrc` file in the home dir of the user the service is being run, and if it doesn't find such file it'll use the default one under `/etc`.